# How to test php webapp that relies on another webapp's api

Tags: php, api, testing

I did some research on the topic and I found nothing, but how to test your own API, which is not my case.

When it comes to database extending classes, I can just fake the data and check if I get the expected results. However, I'm not sure how to implement faking server responses in the most comfortable way.